# Automated Attachment Uploads from local directory

Tags: attachment, upload, automation

I have a directory on a network drive here inside the firewall that has pdfs on it.  I'd like to upload them to salesforce.

There are a lot of tools that do this, but I want it automated--as in, when a file shows up, it gets uploaded.

The upload tools I've used (dataLoader, informatica cloud) require building a csv with filename, parent id.  There's a fairly straightforward conversion between the filename and an external id on the object that I want all these pdfs attached to.

The box they're all on is running windoze, so no bash scripting, please.

What are my options?  Other tools that could be used include dropbox, synctoy.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any out-of-the-box solution that would work, but a custom FOSS-based solution is within reach, possibly even as early as today if you had fair amount of experience with programming.

I would envision that the easiest solution would be a Perl script (ActivePerl is FOSS, works great on Microsoft operating systems). Using [WWW::Salesforce](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Salesforce/) and [File::ChangeNotify](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/File-ChangeNotify-0.24/lib/File/ChangeNotify.pm), you could write a small script (probably 100 lines of code, depending on complexity) that runs in an infinite loop waiting for events:

```
while( my @events = $watcher->wait_for_events() ) {
    while(true) {
        # Call $sfdc->getServerTimestamp() to determine session is active
        # If not, call $sfdc->login() to get a new session
        # continue; // After logging in, try to get new time stamp, or report error
        # Create payload from @events
        # Call $sfdc->create() call to create records
        # report any errors
        # break out of auth/upload loop
    }
}
```

If programming is not your cup of tea, you might look into [Sesame Software](http://www.sesamesoftware.com/products/salesforce/), which has several products that may do what you're looking for out of the box, or [WebSphere Cast Iron Data Loader](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000016Yi8EAE) might also fit the bill. I am not, nor have ever been, affiliated with either company or their software, and I am not certain of their capabilities, but simply providing a few recommendations based on what I've read/heard/seen regarding their products. Other vendors probably have comparable solutions.